# Matching [specific:anything] in PHP

Tags: php, regex

If want to match the following in a string: 
    [test:ANY STRING].

So for example:
    [test:abc]
    [test:thisIsAnotherString]
    [test:y]

What kind of regex would match this?

Comment: Show us [what you've tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).  See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: What regex did you use?  Do you want to match *all* of those in the string?  Why?

Comment: I want to store whatever comes after test: and use it later.

Comment: I have tried "/\[test:.*\]/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, try this

```
$s = 'abc[test:abcd]cb';
$matches = array();
$t = preg_match('#\[test:(.*?)\]#s', $s, $matches);
if($matches[1])
   echo "match";
else
   echo "not";
```

Comment: Good answer. For this, I would have been inclined to put a note about the capturing parenthesis, since this seems to be of particular interest to the OP.